# Would a series of skills-based resume questions be appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to tweak my resume and cannot find the right words to encompass certain skills and was wondering if it would be okay to post a few questions?

Examples:

Question Title: What word can be used to encompass the following hard skills?

Question Body: (start with context about the resume).  What word or phrase can be used to encompass the following hard skills:

- Problem Solving
- Analytical
- Able to Synthesize Data & Information
- Able to see the bigger picture

Question Title: What word can be used to encompass the following soft skills?

Question Body: (start with context about the resume).  What word or phrase can be used to encompass the following soft skills:

- is flexible
- has initiative
- is creative
- is motivated
- is disciplined

Comment: @Fumble, asking if it is OK to post these types of questions is appropriate for Meta.

Comment: @Fumble, the part where he says "I was wondering if it would be OK" and then how he posts two examples of the kind of question he was considering asking, leads me to believe that this is a legitimate Meta question in the vein of "are questions like these on-topic here?" Answering questions like that are on-topic for Meta.

Comment: I take it from the commentary and the down-votes that these questions should not be posted on the main site.  Though, I don't understand why -- the heart of the questions seems to be based on English Language and Usage...

Comment: @ rishimaharaj: As I see it, in both cases you're asking for a single word/phrase to cover several different characteristics/abilities. I'm not clear why *being able to see the bigger picture* is a "hard" skill, but *being disciplined* as a "soft" skill, but let's ignore that. It just seems to me you're effectively trying to conflate attributes whose only real connection is that you see them all as *positive*, and you want to lay claim to them all. But *disciplined* and *creative*, for example, are "opposite" rather than "complementary" attributes. It just looks like writing advice to me.

Comment: @KitFox: Point taken. I'll delete my two earlier comments.

Answer (score 1):

No, these (in the form you have posted them) are "writing advice", which is explicitly off-topic.  I appreciate that you are apparently asking for a single word encompassing certain skills, which is precise enough to be on-topic even if the answer turns out to be "there isn't one"; the problem is that none of these 'skills' are well-defined, and in the context you are just asking for 'a word that will impress'.